# Need some help with my Quartus code since it is not showing my waveform correctly because of an error

Tags: verilog, quartus

I need some help regarding some of my Quartus II work.

[image]

This is the problem I have to solve.

This my code for the 7 segment display and the  multiplexer.  I believe it is correct:

```verilog
module Assignment(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,M3,M2,M1,M0,A3,A2,A1,A0,B3,B2,B1,B0,S,clk);

input S,B3,B2,B1,B0,clk;
output a,b,c,d,e,f,g,M3,M2,M1,M0,A3,A2,A1,A0;
reg A3,A2,A1,A0;


assign a = ~M3&~M2 | ~M2&~M1 | ~M3&~M1&~M0;

assign b = ~M2&~M0 | ~M3&~M0 | ~M3&M1 | ~M2&~M1 | M3&~M1&M0; 


assign c = ~M2&~M0 | ~M2&~M1 | ~M3&~M1&~M0 | ~M3&M1&M0;

assign d = ~M3&~M2 | ~M3&~M1&~M0 | ~M2&~M1&~M0 | M3&M2&M1&~M0;

assign e = ~M3 | M1 | M2&M0;

assign f = ~M3&M0 | ~M2&M1 | ~M3&~M1 | M3&M1&~M0;

assign g = ~M3&~M2 | ~M3&~M1&~M0 | ~M2&~M1&M0 | M3&M2&M1&~M0;

assign M0 = ~S&A0 | S&B0;

assign M1 = ~S&A1 | S&B1;

assign M2 = ~S&A2 | S&B2;

assign M3 = ~S&A3 | S&B3;

always @(posedge clk)
begin


A0 <= ~A0 | ~A3&~A2;

A1 <= A2&~A1&A0 | A3&~A1&A0 | A2&A1&~A0 | A3&A1&~A0;


A2 <= A2&~A0 | ~A3&~A2 | A2&~A1 | ~A2&A1&A0;

A3 <= A3&~A2 | A3&~A0 | A3&~A1 | ~A3&A2&A1&A0;

end

endmodule
```

I'm just not sure where to assign my pins:

[image]

Alongside this, my waveform says that my M3 to M0 is undefined.  I'm not sure on what to do at this point.

Please don't give me flack for this. I'm extremely new to this and just seek help since my teacher doesn't  want to do it.

Comment: i edited my question but i still dont know whats wrong with my code. My teacher said that theres no errors via code or waveform so it must be my internal quartus issue. @jsotola

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer as to which pins you should use for your inputs and outputs, as you don't say whether you are using a specific development board, or a bare chip.

If you're using a dev-kit, then you will need to assign your outputs to whatever pins the dev-kit connects to a 7-segment display (if it has one). The inputs will likely go to switches if available.

I am guessing though from the description that the `Mx` and `Ax` signals should not actually be outputs of the module, but instead be declared locally using `wire` or `reg` as appropriate.

Once you have determined which pins to connect, then you should make the assigments in Quartus. You show a screenshot of the Pin Planner in your question. In the bottom half of this window, there is a column labelled `Location` - this is where you enter the pin numbers you want to assign your inputs and outputs to. *It appears you have already done this*.

---

Undefinied/x values in simulation typically mean one of two things, either you have two or more signals trying to drive the same net (hence undefinied value), **or** you are doing calculations on an unknown value.

For example, consider this code:

```
reg [3:0] a;
always @ (posedge clk) begin
   a <= a + 1;
end
```

What is the value of `a` on the next clock cycle? It's unknown, because we never tell it a starting value. In the simulation you will get a starting value of `xxxx`, so each clock cycle, `a` will be set to `xxxx + 0001 = xxxx`.

If we instead do:

```
reg [3:0] a;
always @ (posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
   if (rst) begin
       a <= 0;
   end else begin
       a <= a + 1;
   end
end
```

At the start of the simulation, we will still see `a` having a value of `xxxx`. However if we now set `rst` high then back low again, now we will see `a` with a value of `0000`. Next clock cycle we will get `a` equal to `0000 + 0001 = 0001`, and so on. It counts as expected.

You have a similar issue with the values of your registers A0 through A3. Each clock cycle they rely on knowing their value in the previous clock cycle. You never set a default or reset them to a known state, so they will always be `x`, as will everything else which uses them.

Comment: oh the board is on a max700ae and my professor said the code was right its just that im getting undefined errors on the waveform now.